# Pandas - Group by multiple columns and datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by

I have a df of tennis results and I would like to be able to see how many days its been since each player last won a game.

This is what my df looks like

| Player 1 | Player 2 | Date | p1_win | p2_win |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Murray | Nadal | 2022-05-16 | 1 | 0 |
| Nadal | Murray | 2022-05-25 | 1 | 0 |

and this is what I want it to look like

| Player 1 | Player 2 | Date | p1_win | p2_win | p1_lastwin | p2_lastwin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Murray | Nadal | 2022-05-16 | 1 | 0 | na | na |
| Nadal | Murray | 2022-05-25 | 1 | 0 | na | 9 |

the results will have to be able to include the days since the last win whether the player was player 1 or 2 using group by I think. Also maybe if possible it would be good to have a win percentage for the year if possible.
Any help is much appreciated.

edit - here is the dict

```
{'Player 1': {0: 'Murray',
  1: 'Nadal',
  2: 'Murray',
  3: 'Nadal',
  4: 'Murray',
  5: 'Nadal',
  6: 'Murray',
  7: 'Nadal',
  8: 'Murray',
  9: 'Nadal',
  10: 'Murray'},
 'Player 2': {0: 'Nadal',
  1: 'Murray',
  2: 'Nadal',
  3: 'Murray',
  4: 'Nadal',
  5: 'Murray',
  6: 'Nadal',
  7: 'Murray',
  8: 'Nadal',
  9: 'Murray',
  10: 'Nadal'},
 'Date': {0: '2022-05-16',
  1: '2022-05-26',
  2: '2022-05-27',
  3: '2022-05-28',
  4: '2022-05-29',
  5: '2022-06-01',
  6: '2022-06-02',
  7: '2022-06-05',
  8: '2022-06-09',
  9: '2022-06-13',
  10: '2022-06-17'},
 'p1_win': {0: '1',
  1: '1',
  2: '0',
  3: '1',
  4: '0',
  5: '0',
  6: '1',
  7: '0',
  8: '1',
  9: '0',
  10: '1'},
 'p2_win': {0: '0',
  1: '0',
  2: '1',
  3: '0',
  4: '1',
  5: '1',
  6: '0',
  7: '1',
  8: '0',
  9: '1',
  10: '0'}}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you add the larger part of the data? so we will be able to see how you derived the 9 in p2_lastwin

Comment: The 9 comes from the first game (top row) in which Murray won. therefore in the second game (second row) it has been 9 days since Murrays last win

Comment: and what's the full dataset? share a sample of at least 10 rows (as a dict) and I'll help

Comment: {'Player 1': {0: 'Murray',
  1: 'Nadal',
  2: 'Murray',
  3: 'Nadal',
  4: 'Murray',
  5: 'Nadal',
  6: 'Murray'},
 'Player 2': {0: 'Nadal',
  1: 'Murray',
  2: 'Nadal',
  3: 'Murray',
  4: 'Nadal',
  5: 'Murray',
  6: 'Nadal'},
 'Date': {0: '2022-05-16',
  1: '2022-05-26',
  2: '2022-05-27',
  3: '2022-05-28',
  4: '2022-05-29',
  5: '2022-06-01',
  6: '2022-06-02'},
 'p1_win': {0: '1', 1: '1', 2: '0', 3: '1', 4: '0', 5: '0', 6: '1'},
 'p2_win': {0: '0', 1: '0', 2: '1', 3: '0', 4: '1', 5: '1', 6: '0'}}

Comment: 10 rows was too many characters to comment

Comment: Maybe edit the question :)

Answer (score 0):

I leveraged `pd.merge_asof` to find the latest win, and then did a `merge` to the relevant index.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Player 1': {0: 'Murray', 1: 'Nadal', 2: 'Murray', 3: 'Nadal', 4: 'Murray', 5: 'Nadal', 6: 'Murray'}, 'Player 2': {0: 'Nadal', 1: 'Murray', 2: 'Nadal', 3: 'Murray', 4: 'Nadal', 5: 'Murray', 6: 'Nadal'}, 'Date': {0: '2022-05-16', 1: '2022-05-26', 2: '2022-05-27', 3: '2022-05-28', 4: '2022-05-29', 5: '2022-06-01', 6: '2022-06-02'}, 'p1_win': {0: '1', 1: '1', 2: '0', 3: '1', 4: '0', 5: '0', 6: '1'}, 'p2_win': {0: '0', 1: '0', 2: '1', 3: '0', 4: '1', 5: '1', 6: '0'}})
df['p1_win']=df.p1_win.astype(int)
df['p2_win']=df.p2_win.astype(int)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['match'] = [x+'_'+y if x>y else y+'_'+x for x,y in zip(df['Player 1'],df['Player 2'])]
# df['winner'] = np.where(df.p1_win==1,df['Player 1'],df['Player 2'])
# df['looser'] = np.where(df.p1_win==0,df['Player 1'],df['Player 2'])
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.sort_values(by='Date')

df = pd.merge_asof(df,df[df.p1_win==1][['match','Date','index']],by=['match'],on='Date',suffixes=('','_latest_win_p1'),allow_exact_matches=False,direction='backward')
df = pd.merge_asof(df,df[df.p2_win==1][['match','Date','index']],by=['match'],on='Date',suffixes=('','_latest_win_p2'),allow_exact_matches=False,direction='backward')

# df = df[['index','Date','Player 1','Player 2','p1_win','p2_win','match','winner','looser','index_latest_win_p2','index_latest_win_p1']]



df = df.merge(df[['Date','index','match']],how='left',left_on=['index_latest_win_p1','match'],right_on=['index','match'],suffixes=('','_latest_win_winner'))
df = df.merge(df[['Date','index','match']],how='left',left_on=['index_latest_win_p2','match'],right_on=['index','match'],suffixes=('','_latest_win_looser'))
df['days_since_last_win_winner'] = (df['Date']-df.Date_latest_win_winner).dt.days
df['days_since_last_win_looser'] = (df['Date']-df.Date_latest_win_looser).dt.days
```

not sure that this is exactly what you meant but let me know if you need anything else:

Comment: thanks for the help but im getting the error "The column label 'index_latest_winner' is not unique." Also player 1 doesn't mean they won its just they are player 1. same with player 2 doesn't mean they lost its just player 2

Comment: thats why i added winner/looser

Comment: ah right thanks. do you know why its saying "The column label 'index_latest_winner' is not unique."

Comment: edited to match what you wanted

Comment: thanks for the help but its not working. no worries tho thanks anyways :)

Comment: What's not working? Works for me. Let me know and I'll help

Comment: so the sample data works for me perfectly but when I use it on my full dataset I get the error 'The column label 'index_latest_win_p1' is not unique.' not sure why it would work on sample dataset and not the full thing

Comment: can you share the full sample?

Comment: what's the best way to share?